# French equivalent of "just in case"?

Tags: expressions, locutions

I'd like to know how a French speaker might express this, especially when nothing specific follows it, e.g.

> One of these things is usually enough, but I've bought a second one, just in case.
>
> Un seul de ces machins suffit normalement, mais j'en ai acheté un deuxième, …

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Au cas où*. Grammatically, one should complete with the situation where it would be useful, but it is very common not to expand it.

> Un seul de ces machins suffit normalement, mais j'en ai acheté un deuxième, au cas où…

Comment: Could raisonably be written `juste au cas où` to match `**just** in case`.

Comment: While there are not completing phrase, Frenchies like to terminate with tree dots, like this: in case...

Answer (score 2):

Ou :

- *par précaution*
- *on ne sait jamais*
- *à tout hasard*
- *des fois que ...* (familier)
- *tout peut arriver*